# Play Framework соединение с БД

Tags: java, oracle, playframework

Не могу настроить соединение с базой в `Play`
а именно драйвер `Oracle` не правильно, может кто знает?

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

написал таким вот образом мне отвечает

```
Driver not found: [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
```

Comment: он не может найти драйвер но раньше я работал с мавеном и я не подключал джарники, не знаете куда надо добавить папку lib c jar-ником?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

методом тыка нашел [ответ](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Anatomy) и разобрался

Comment: Не тянет на ответ. Вопрос закрывать как решенный?

Comment: по той же структуре я создал папку Lib и закинул jar-ник через cmd запустил обратно проект и заработало